# jQuery AJAX post method throws 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, post

I'm new in AJAX and have been learning the functions of jQuery get() and post() methods recently. While the get() method worked smoothly, I've faltered while coming across the post() method, that throws an error saying: "405 (Method not allowed)" every time I try to invoke it.

Using Bootstrap, I have a simple HTML file named get_post.html that has a div, paragraph and button elements each. Using jQuery, on the click event of the button, I'm sending a name and location using post() method to a php file named mypost.php that will process the data and send a string of message back to get_post.html. I want to show the final message in the paragraph element of get_post.html. While trying to achieve this, every time I click on the button, the browser console shows the error message mentioned above. Assuming the problem is somehow related to CORS policy, I must mention that both the get_post.html and the mypost.php files reside in the same folder under the same domain. So how come it's a CORS policy-related error? Moreover, I'm using Node.js http-server localhost to run the get_post.html file. Hence, any issue related to localhost is unlikely too. Besides, I enabled and disabled CORS while running http-server, but of no avail. I also tried using IIS, but the same problem arises there as well.

So, what might be causing the error and how can I get rid of it? As I'm new in AJAX, I'm not much used to the intricacies of it. Most of the online solutions are not related to my scenario; therefore, I couldn't obtain much help from them. Please assist in sorting this out, if possible with a basic-level example.

get_post.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p id="loadedData">This is where data will be loaded from server dynamically.</p>
            <button class="btnLoad btn btn-primary">Load Data</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".btnLoad").click(function() {
                    // Fetching data using post() method.
                    $.post("mypost.php", {
                        name: "Firstname Lastname",
                        location: "Countryname"
                    }, function(data, status) {
                        $("#loadedData").html(data);
                        alert(status);
                    });
                });
             });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

mypost.php code:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];

    echo "This is ".$name.". I'm from ".$location".";
?>
```

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: It's not the JS or CORS. The message comes from your server, you've to adjust your server configurations to make it to handle POST requests.

Comment: @Teemu: Assuming localhost is what you're referring to as server, as I mentioned in my post, I tried both enabling and disabling CORS in the Node.js http-server I'm using as localhost. But in either case it shows the same error. I also tried using IIS, which too throws the same error. In this scenario, can you please explain what configurations do I need to make on http-server or IIS to make them handle POST requests. I'm at the beginner level; hence, a little clarification will help immensely.

Comment: "localhost" is just an address, ex. I'm running Apache in my "localhost". What are you running in the localhost?

Comment: Localhost contains the project folder in which the get_post.html and mypost.php files reside, along with other html files.

Comment: As I'm using Node.js http-server, you can make your project folder the localhost by passing the path of your project folder while starting the http-server. However, while trying IIS, I'm pasting my project folder in C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: Node.js doesn't run PHP, you've to install ex. Apcahe and PHP compiler in order to run PHP.

Comment: @Teemu: OK. But what about IIS. It's showing the same error too. Can't IIS run PHP either? How do I configure IIS to run PHP in that case?

Comment: The first hit when searchig looks promising: https://stackify.com/how-to-host-php-on-windows-with-iis/ I've installed a WAPP package from [Bitnami](https://stackify.com/how-to-host-php-on-windows-with-iis/), those might not be the latest versions, though.

Comment: Thanks for the stackify link. It was significant enough to iron out my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] throws an error saying: "405 (Method not allowed)" every time I try
> to invoke it.

You're making a request for a route that doesn't accept the Post method and so it gives an error. Here explains it:

> 405 Method Not Allowed The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405
> Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the server
> knows the request method, but the target resource doesn't support this
> method.
>
> The server must generate an Allow header field in a 405 status code
> response. The field must contain a list of methods that the target
> resource currently supports.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Since you are apparently just using pure PHP with no frameworks or dependencies, you should check which type of request is being received.

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
print_r($method);
```

If the code above returns something other than POST, you have something blocking Post requests somewhere, try using it without Jquery / Ajax, if it works, it may be the case to send an additional header or a token depending on your configuration.

Comment: In the comments OP says, that they've Node.js running, it looks like PHP will never be executed.

Comment: @Teemu I think the OP is making some confusion as in the question it says GET requests work so PHP is running somewhere. Nodo.js server can be installed in parallel with Apache/Nginx

Comment: GET request works on an HTML file. Haven't tried GET on any php file yet.

Comment: @priyamtheone See on this page how to install PHP on your IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php

Comment: Thanks for this link. It helped me in sorting out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was all about the PHP file not supporting the post() method.

Two things helped me zero in on the root of the problem. Firstly, @Teemu stated that **Node.js http-server doesn't run php** despite serving as a localhost. Secondly, @Macedo_Montalvão mentioned: **"405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the server knows the request method, but the target resource doesn't support this method."** That intrigued me to install a dedicated PHP server. So, I hosted PHP on Windows with IIS as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php) and [here](https://stackify.com/how-to-host-php-on-windows-with-iis/). Thereafter, I hosted my project folder from within IIS and now, the post() method works perfectly and the two pages communicate as well as required.

However, there was a typo in my code. In the mypost.php file, there will be a `.` after `$location` at the end of the `echo` statement, which I overlooked. That was throwing a 500 (Internal Server Error).

Thanks @Teemu and @Macedo_Montalvão for your suggestions and sharing those two invaluable links. Stay well!

Regards!